# CorePlot: Changing datasource on zooming from monthly to daily ScatterPlot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I got a working Scatterplot showing monthly average recorded weights. I dunno if this is possible, but I would like to convert it into a day-based chart when zoomed in, and back to monthly when zoomed out.

I tried using

```
-(void)scaleBy: (CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint: (CGPoint)interactionPoint
```

But I can't make out if its zoomed in or out using `interactionScale`

Here's the Datasource code if needed

```
- (NSNumber *)numberForPlot: (CPTPlot *)plot field: (NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex: (NSUInteger)index {
    switch (fieldEnum) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX: 
            if (index < 13) {
                if (index == 0)
                    return nil;

                //NSLog(@"x coordinate: %i",index);
                return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger: index];
            }
            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY: 
            if (index == 0)
                return nil;

            //NSLog(@"y coordinate: %i", [[weights objectAtIndex: index]integerValue]);

            if ([[weights objectAtIndex: index]integerValue] <= 0)
                return nil;
            else return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger: [[weights objectAtIndex: index]integerValue]];

            break;
    }

    return [NSDecimalNumber zero];
}

- (CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot: (CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex: (NSUInteger)idx {
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleTextStyle.fontSize = 10.0;
    axisTitleTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];

    CPTTextLayer *label = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] init];
    label.textStyle = axisTitleTextStyle;
    label.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", [[weights objectAtIndex: idx] floatValue]];

    return label;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do more than just change the plot ranges (which is what `-scaleBy:aboutPoint:` does) to change from summary to detailed data. You also will need to give the plot new data (`-reloadData`) and update the axis labels to indicate the new scale.

If you need to change states in response to user action, e.g., when the user zooms past a certain point, monitor changes to the plot space ranges with a delegate and update the data and labels when they cross the change threshold.

Comment: Where should I put the data source changing and then reloadData logic?

Comment: It depends on what triggers the change. For example, if pressing a button changes the scale, put it in the button's action method.